# Yandex mapkit отображение карты

Tags: android, xml, yandexmapkit

При добавлении карты Yandex, она имеет вид прямоугольника. Возможно ли как-то сделать её вывод со скругленными углами?

```
    <com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Положи ее внутрь CardView, у которого есть xml атрибут `app:cardCornerRadius`